# mongod Failed to obtain address information for hostname OS X

Tags: macos, mongodb

Having an issue starting mongo using mongod --dbpath.  I get the following error:

```
NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain address information for hostname ##########: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Host name only has latin characters.  I've tried multiple networks, deleted all DNS entries, confirmed my /etc/hosts looks fine and now I'm at a standstill.

Here is my /etc/hosts:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
#::1             localhost
```

Comment: Did you get it running somehow? I tried adding 127.0.0.1 [your user] no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the ipv6 and restart the mongod server

```
::1             localhost
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11872542)

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam How is this a comment? It has a specific suggestion at solving the problem. If you think that this *answer* is wrong or otherwise bad, then you can downvote it. Please don't abuse your deletion privileges in this review queue.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answer in this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20952) ticket.

And here is my `/etc/hosts` file.

```
  1 ##
  2 # Host Database
  3 #
  4 # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
  5 # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
  6 ##
  7 # 127.0.0.1 localhost
  8 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
  9 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
 10 # ::1             localhost
```

Answer (score -2):

change your `HOSTNAME` in `/etc/sysconfig/network` likes:

```
HOSTNAME=Steven
```

Then change your hostname in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain ...............
```

to

```
127.0.0.1 localhost Steven  ...............
```